# HP DL360 G7 Smart Array P410i drive mix

Tags: raid, hp-proliant, ssd

i have HP DL360 G7 Smart Array P410i with 3xSAS HDD 146 GB in RAID5.
I decided to change hard drives to SSD ones (3x180 Intel SSD).
My idea was to change drives one by one and wait for RAID rebuilds.

However, i got this
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8uO4.jpg)

i suppose reason is type 
[mix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBEjE.png)

so my question is - maybe there is some workaround, how to force RAID rebuild without new RAID creation on new SSD's and system installation/restore.

any advice is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You cannot mix SAS and SATA drives in the same array, doesn't matter SSD or not. Buy SAS SSDs - and you could migrate without downtime - exactly as you planned

Comment: sounds reasonable, thanks! one question - under "same array" you mean physical controller or logical array? because currently i have 3 SAS drives in RAID5 (Array A) and 1 SATA drive RAID0 (Array B), and it works fine.

Comment: Logical array. Controller supports sata arrays and sas arrays no problems

Answer (score 3):

Mixing SSD and HDD within the RAID array is not supported unless the enclosure supports it. 
Why don't you just backup the data, and then restore it on the new RAID array?
For example using Veeam Backup agent on Linux and then restore once new RAID array comes back online

Comment: Also use HP drives, they're notorious for not playing nicely with non-HP ones.

Comment: yes it's clear that mixing is not supported, this error is self explained obviously. and of course backup/restore is possible solution, but my question is - does anybody know *workaround* possible for such case?